# Custom archive pages without "the loop"

Tags: archives, custom-post-type-archives

Is there a way that I could control the rendering of an archive page that uses my own loop? I'd like to group the posts by a custom taxonomy, then sort them by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should filter the default `$query` via callback hooked into `pre_get_posts`:

```
function wpse108983_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    // Make sure we're targeting
    // the main loop query, and
    // only in the archive context
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_archive() ) {
        // Add your query modifications here
        // For example, to sort by date:
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse108983_filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

If you need to output multiple loops in order to group by taxonomy, you will, instead of the above approach, want to output *custom* loops via `new WP_Query()`.

Assuming that you already know how to query terms for your taxonomy `foobar`, and have them in an array, `$term_array`:

```
// Loop through each term
foreach ( $term_array as $single_term ) {
    // Generate the term query
    $term_query = new WP_Query(
        'foobar' => $single_term,
        'orderby' => 'date'
    );
    // Output the term query loop
    if ( $term_query->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $term_query->have_posts() ) : 
            $term_query->the_post();
            // Custom loop markup goes here
            // Use normal loop template tags, such as
            // the_content(), the_permalink(), etc
        endwhile; 
    endif;
    // Important; don't forget this!
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: when is `pre_get_posts` best registered? I want to hook into the resulting query, modify it, and return different objects.

Comment: `pre_get_posts` is an action, that allows you to do exactly what you say: hook into the query object, and modify it, before the query retrieves posts. You simply need to write a callback, and hook it into `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: could you edit your answer and expand on that? where does the callback get written? does it go in a `functions` file or can i put it in a template file?

Comment: Callbacks and `add_action()` calls **always** go in `functions.php` if part of a Theme.

Comment: Thanks Chip! I was able to create the object structure i would need to loop over.